# How to collect Dust transactions?

Tags: transaction-fees, armory, dust

Most of my initially received bitcoins were from faucets and therefore, these micro amounts ended up being dust transactions. Since then, I've bought some bitcoins which are not dust.

Now I'm trying to send 0.0005 BTC to test out Blockchain.info's "receive payment API" (http://blockchain.info/api/api_receive) PHP example (https://github.com/blockchain/receive_payment_php_demo).  But Bitcoin-QT is telling me that I must pay 0.0005 BTC transaction fee.

I found out that the fee is due to the dust transactions.  Now, I like to get rid of these dust transactions  by combining their amounts.  Can anyone suggest an easy way to do this?

I was thinking of installing Armory and then transferring all of my bitcoins from my Bitcoin-QT wallet, in one transaction, to my Armory wallet.  Will this eliminate the dust transactions by combining all of my dust amounts together?  Will my new Armory wallet contain just one input transaction, and not over a dozen transactions of small amounts?

If Armory is not the way to collect the dust transactions, can someone explain how to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine all the tiny amounts I've received to minimise transaction fees, and do I need to?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5583/how-can-i-combine-all-the-tiny-amounts-ive-received-to-minimise-transaction-fee)

Comment: The answer at http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5583/how-can-i-combine-all-the-tiny-amounts-ive-received-to-minimise-transaction-fee seems more complicated than UNIX.  It talks about using Eligius mining pool to consolidate the dust transactions.  But how do I do this?  I took a look at Eligius and I don't see any explanation of consolidating dust.  The answer states:  "As for combining the "dust" while leaving larger balances alone -- you would have to find a client that allows you to choose the inputs to your transaction. I don't know which clients can do that."  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it myself, but Peter Todd has a python script called dust-b-gone.py

https://github.com/petertodd/dust-b-gone

Comment: This would be great, but how do you use it, I really do not know Python, the read me says to unzip it, but I do not have a clue how to do this. Complicated for the average Joe.