# Transaction too large error

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I have over 1400 small transactions in my wallet that add up to a little over 0.2 BTC. I am trying to send them, but keep getting a transaction too large error. I have tried to set a custom transaction fee, but am unable to still send. I am using Bitcoin core v0.10 on Windows. I have looked at this thread but am still unable to find a solution.

[How can I combine all the tiny amounts I've received to minimise transaction fees, and do I need to?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5583/how-can-i-combine-all-the-tiny-amounts-ive-received-to-minimise-transaction-fee)

Comment: Does it say 'Transaction too large' or 'Transaction too large for fee policy?' They're different errors.

Comment: It says just says "Transaction too large"

Answer (score 3):

Your scriptSig is too big! It is limited to 200 kbytes, and you've got *1400 inputs @ 0.2kbyte* (best case scenario): `1400x 200 = 280`kbyte.

Try using half the inputs (preferably newer inputs) to cut the scriptSig down in size.

Comment: Why newer inputs? Wouldn't older inputs have a higher priority?

Comment: @NickODell Yep, just "picking the better half" so to speak

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie The older ones are the better ones.

Comment: @PieterWuille I personally would try sweeping up the *worse (newer) ones* to hopefully comprise a fee-free Tx. I'm not disputing the priority being inversely proportional to age; it's more a difference in opinion of how to handle dust, but tbh, I'll defer to you  here!

Comment: Priority is proportional to age, not inversely. And every output spent has its own scriptSig in the txin, which is around 105 bytes total per output spent.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been able to send out various smaller sized amounts (0.0004 BTC). I looks like I will have to slowly transfer out the remaining balance in smaller transactions.

Comment: I had over 1600 Transactions and was getting "Transaction too large" message. I cut down the inputs to 600 transactions and was able to send without issue. Your answer above helped me resolve this.