# Am I making a lot of dust in my wallet?

Tags: wallet, dust

If I make a lot of little transactions, sending and receiving various odd small amounts (like 0.00201, 0.00319), does this make lots of little dust bits in my wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. You'll notice increased fees and confirmation times eventually. Those amounts aren't super dusty though, even smaller transactions are the ones that will really bog you down.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there as way to consolidate the dust?

Comment: @obelia: See for example [In order to reduce fees, can I 'consolidate' my wallet by sending the entire balance to a new address in the same wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/792/in-order-to-reduce-fees-can-i-consolidate-my-wallet-by-sending-the-entire-bal) or [How can I combine all the tiny amounts I've received to minimise transaction fees, and do I need to?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5583/how-can-i-combine-all-the-tiny-amounts-ive-received-to-minimise-transaction-fee)